# Can not file share library on Django and Nginx

Tags: django, nginx, ctypes, shared

I have a problem with project django + nginx for call share library. I don't know path of library file to call. I have tried with all of case . I don't know where I have to put library file on server to call correctly.

This erros here :

```
OSError at /list/

media/documents/lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http : / /127 .0.0.1:8000/list/
Django Version: 1.4
Exception Type: OSError
Exception Value:    

media/documents/lib.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py in __init__, line 365
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version: 2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/ht/workspace/myproject/src',
 '/home/ht/workspace/myproject/src',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-client',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-control-panel',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-couch',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-installer',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntuone-storage-protocol']
Server time:    Fri, 27 Jul 2012 08:49:53 -0500
```

Comment: Post the *full* stacktrace, and you have 4 answered question that you have not accepted. Help will be hard to find if you don't accept answers people give you.